# Taylor expansion of two variable function without cross terms

Tags: functions, matrix, inverse

I have the matrix symmetric matrix

```
g={{a[x],        b[x],        c[x],         d[x]},
   {b[x],  1/(1-a[x]),           0,            0},
   {c[x],           0,  1/(1-a[x]),            0},
   {d[x],           0,           0,  1/(1-a[x])}}
```

And I want to make a function who returns the inverse matrix in Taylor expansion linear in  $a,b,c,d$, without their cross terms. After a little search I made this

```
 InverseMatrix[g_] := 
         Normal[Series[Simplify[Inverse[g]] /. {a[x] -> ε a[x], b[x] -> ε b[x],
```

c[x] -> ε c[x], d[x] -> ε d[x]}, {ε, 0, 1}]] /. [Epsilon] -> 1;

But doesn't work as I want.

Comment: Is `a(x)` supposed to be `a[x]`? or why are there brackets? If you could give an example of the desired result, that might help clarify things. You probably want linearity in $a'$, $b'$ etc., right? In that case you just made a syntax mistake.

Comment: Sorry I meant a[x], copied wrong. In my code I have it a[x].
The results I hope to get is linearity in the a,b,c,d.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is probably this:

```
InverseMatrix[g_] := 
  Normal[Series[
  Simplify[
   Inverse[g]] /. {f_[x] :> ε f[x]}, {ε, 0, 
  1}]] /. ε -> 1;
```

The parameter `ε` is not meant to be introduced in front of the function argument `x`, but in front of the functions themselves, if you want to expand to a consistent order in all of them.

Comment: I am so sorry. You are right I make it wrong again when I copy.
Thank you so much!

Comment: And If I want one function not to be expand, lets say a[x]?

Comment: @JonSnow You could change the named pattern `f_[x]` to `(f : Except[a])[x]` Here `f` is still the label for the pattern representing a function of `x`, but using `Except` I now exclude `a[x]`.

Comment: And Something last!!! If I want to expand a[x] up to second power, and keep the others only the linear terms?
I am noob in mathematica, I will be happy if you could suggest me a good book to read

Comment: I'd recommend reading the help documentation under `tutorial/PatternsOverview`. And of course searching this site. You could append another replacement rule to the one I gave. I don't understand how you want to keep track of the different orders, so I can't be more specific. The rule would involve `a[x]-> a[ε x]`.

Comment: I mean for example one of the elements to be 1+a+a^2+b.
I dont know how to put the extra rule. I am trying this `/. {a[x] :> ε a[x]}, {ε, 0,2}, {b[x] :> ε b[x]}, {ε,0,1}]] /. ε -> 1;`

Comment: The easiest is probably to just do the expansion exactly as shown in my answer first, then follow it with an identical copy of what I wrote, except that you use the rule `/. a[x] -> ε a[x]` on the result of the first step, with the order of `Series` increased to `2`. You can't do what you tried because you somehow mixed the arguments of `Series` in with the rule.

Comment: `a[x]`,`b[x]` and `d[x]` are O(1) (first order) terms and `c[x]` is O(2) (second order), How can I expand the inverse metric and keep only second order term. For example `a[x]*b[x]` is acceptable, `a[x]^2` and `c[x]` also, but `c[x]*a[x]` is not.